# Users kick off to the login page

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net application hosted on IIS6.0  which was working fine . Last week I asked admin team to free some space on the server. After that the application start showing some strange behavior. Users  are getting kicked off to the login page(idle or working) after 15 minutes. I have tried all setting on IIS6.0 and web.config and everything appear correct over there. Please help.

Comment: Normally the session state is twenty minutes and expires when the users are not working. Can you show your web.config?

Comment: I have increased session time out value. Here is my web config

Comment: <pageStore mode="NoStore"unloadStoredPage="false"cacheTimeout="5"maxConcurrentPages="5"maxPagesLimitAlert="false"/>
 </magicAjax>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="50" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:20" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="30"/>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5000" executionTimeout="6000"/>